# Different menu links depending on user account

Tags: users, routes

I need to create menu that has to be diffrent for each user.

```
/user/%username%
/user/%username%/purchases
etc.
```

Is there way to do something like that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes . You can use  [Menu Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token). (Menu Token module provides tokens, that could be used in title or in path of menu items. For example, if you create a menu item with path: "user/[current-user:uid]", the url will be changed "on fly" to: "user/1" )

Answer (score 0):

I found the way that is not really good for me, but it is acceptable. I define items in hook_menu, and combine my meny with primary_tabs